# str_replace to remove string from $_SESSION

Tags: php, string, session, str-replace

I save a reuested URI into a SESSION by using:

```
$_SESSION['uri'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Now I have a form that will be submitted and in case of no entry the page should be reloaded with the information from the GET-parameters. So I usually thought to check if the stored URI already contains the String with the GET-parameters by simply using `str_replace('&error=empty', '', $_SESSION['uri']);` but it seems that this function does not work and I have no clue why.

Here is an example from the original code where the form is submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['send']) === true && empty($_POST['suggestion'])) {
    if ( isset($_GET['error']) === true ) {
        header ('Location: '.$_SESSION['uri'].'withoutstringerror');
    } else {    
        header ('Location: '.$_SESSION['uri'].'&error=empty');
    }
```

The header-function is necessary because if the form will be submitted and there is no entry all the GET-parameters will be lost. That is why I have to store the original URI and use the header-function to keep the information. The problem with the code above is that when submitting the form and there is no entry it adds the `&error=empty`again. I thought it would be the best solution to check if there is already that string in the URI and replace it by using `str_replace()`

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking: How to retrieve the $_GET-array from a request?

Comment: NO... I'm asking why I can't delete a string from a SESSION.

Comment: Do you assign str_replace() to a variable? str_replace() returns a value. It doesn't modify the variable you pass into the parameter. Also, if you wish to remove a variable you've set in a session, just use unset().

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski when I echo SESSION['uri'] there is the complete string. So you are wrong when you write that '&error=empty' never have been present.

Comment: @John My mistake - confused with Apache, wherein REQUEST_URI does not include the query string, and [PHP's documentation is nonspecific](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['uri'] = str_replace('&error=empty', '', $_SESSION['uri']);
```

I think you've just missed assigning the return value from `str_replace()` to your session variable. `str_replace()` doesn't modify the variable you pass in by parameter directly, it returns a new value, based on the function call.